# Deploying multiple react apps on a single host on different paths

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have 2 react applications, one of which is served on example.com and it works fine.
Now I am working on a second application and I need it to be served on example.com/app.
I am using nginx as ingress.

Note:
Both apps run on seperate docker containers on AKS in same namespace.

Please find my ingress.yaml as below -

App1 served on example.com (works fine)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: app1
                port:
                  number: 80
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
```

App2 which I need to serve on example.com/app (doesn't work). When I open example.com/app/ I see a blank page and no errors.  When I open example.com/app the bundles fail to load.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app2
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  labels:
    app: app2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: app2
                port:
                  number: 80
            path: /app(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
```

Comment: You need 2 things: Rewrite the URL to remove leading `/app` when forwarding, and to supply a `homepage` entry of `/app` in the apps `package.json`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @super could you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: @Striker When building the react app you need to configure it to be served on the correct base path, in this case `/app`. If you use CRA you do it by setting the `homepage` option in your `package.json`. With vite it's `base` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about the serving **example.com/app** not sure how your internal application showing or serving the data.

Can't you just do like

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-svc
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /app
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: svc2
            port:
              number: 80
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

You can also separate out the two different ingress hosts with diff name

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /apps(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: svc-2
            port: 
              number: 80
```

while the other one is without the rule of rewrite forwarding all traffic to **svc-1**.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. Had tried similar thing

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `"homepage": "https://example.com/app"` in my package.json to make it work.